# OpenGL What need to reconfig when rotate screen

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I have to make a lib for iOS. There is one UIView class which must support rotation. This class currently using OpenGL ES 1.0 to draw everything. There no problem when the view is in portrait orientation. But when i rotate device / emulator, everything i draw become blurry, not much. I check but they didn't seem like they got stretched. So i thing the reason is that i need to reconfig something in OpenGL like my render buffer after it got rotation. But i'm don't know exactly which one. I'm rather new to OpenGL, because i'm work mostly with Web / Core function.

So if anyone can give me any advice about this matter, please. Which normally should i do when i rotate screen when using OpenGL?
Also please tell me if i need to provide any code for this case.

Thank you

Comment: Did you get this solved?

Comment: Sorry this problem still remain for me. But since as i said, it not really much, so we just kind of accept it for now. But still hope i can solve this problem soon

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this solves your problem or not, but at least it solved mine, so I'll share what I found. My code is in C# via OpenTK, but the OpenGLES interfaces are the same, so I'm pretty sure you can do the same thing in your code.

The thing is that when the device is rotated, the renderbuffer has to be recreated with the landscape dimensions. If you don't do this, the EAGL context will stretch your renderbuffer and make it fit the screen. You will then have squished pixels in the vertical axis, and stretched pixels in the horizontal axis.

This is how I recreate my renderbuffer (in C#) when I detect a rotation (`WillRotate`)

```
public void ResizeFrameBuffer(int newWidth, int newHeight)
{
    DeviceWidth = newWidth;
    DeviceHeight = newHeight;

    Size = new System.Drawing.Size(DeviceWidth, DeviceHeight);
    Bounds = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0, 0, DeviceWidth, DeviceHeight);

    MakeCurrent();

    GL.DeleteRenderbuffers(1, ref renderbuffer);

    GL.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, Framebuffer);
    GL.GenRenderbuffers(1, out renderbuffer);
    GL.BindRenderbuffer(RenderbufferTarget.Renderbuffer, renderbuffer);
    EAGLContext.RenderBufferStorage((uint)RenderbufferTarget.Renderbuffer, (CAEAGLLayer)Layer);
    GL.FramebufferRenderbuffer(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, FramebufferSlot.ColorAttachment0, RenderbufferTarget.Renderbuffer, renderbuffer);
    GL.Viewport(0, 0, DeviceWidth, DeviceHeight);
    GL.Scissor(0, 0, DeviceWidth, DeviceHeight);

    Frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0, 0, DeviceWidth, DeviceHeight);
}
```

There is a bit more information in the [question I posted on the Game Development SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/75965/), so you may want to check that one out as well.

Comment: I know that i need to recreate render buffer. I did try that but somehow i got mess up. Maybe i did something incorrect before. But for now, we are moving to new place as well as working on a web project so i can't try your code yet. I will reply whenever i have a chance to work with my iOS app.

Answer (score 1):

You can rotate the OpenGL output in the vertex shader as follows:

```
#version 300 es


in vec4 position;
in mediump vec4 texturecoordinate;

in vec4 color;

uniform float preferredRotation;

out mediump vec2 coordinate;

void main()
{
    //const float pi = 4.0 * atan(1.0);
    //float radians  = (( -90.0 ) / 180.0 * pi );

    // Preferred rotation of video acquired, for example, by:
    // AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [tracks objectAtIndex:0];
    // CGAffineTransform preferredTransform = [videoTrack preferredTransform];
    // self.glKitView.preferredRotation = -1 * atan2(preferredTransform.b, preferredTransform.a);

    // Preferred rotation for both portrait and landscape           
    mat4 rotationMatrix = mat4( cos(preferredRotation), -sin(preferredRotation), 0.0, 0.0,
                                sin(preferredRotation),  cos(preferredRotation), 0.0, 0.0,
                                0.0,                     0.0,                    1.0, 0.0,
                                0.0,                     0.0,                    0.0, 1.0);

    // Mirror vertical (portrait only)
    mat4 rotationMatrix = mat4( cos(preferredRotation),  sin(preferredRotation), 0.0, 0.0,
                               -sin(preferredRotation),  cos(preferredRotation), 0.0, 0.0,
                                0.0,           0.0,          1.0, 0.0,
                                0.0,           0.0,          0.0, 1.0);

    // Mirror horizontal (landscape only)
    mat4 rotationMatrix = mat4( 1.0, 0.0,                     0.0,                    0.0,
                                0.0, cos(preferredRotation), -sin(preferredRotation), 0.0,
                                0.0, sin(preferredRotation),  cos(preferredRotation), 0.0,
                                0.0, 0.0,                     0.0,                    1.0);

    // Mirror vertical (landscape only)
    mat4 rotationMatrix = mat4( cos(preferredRotation), 0.0, sin(preferredRotation), 0.0,
                                0.0,                    1.0, 0.0,                    0.0,
                               -sin(preferredRotation), 0.0, cos(preferredRotation), 0.0,
                                0.0,                    0.0, 0.0,                    1.0);

    gl_Position = position * rotationMatrix;
    coordinate = texturecoordinate.xy;
}
```

Obviously, you choose only one matrix4, depending on the orientation of the video, and then its rotation. Each matrix4 flips the video window -- not rotates it. For rotation, you have to first pick the matrix4 based on the orientation, and then substitute the preferredRotation variable with the number of degrees (in radians, the formula for which is also provided).

There are a lot of ways to rotate a view, layer, object, etc.; but, if you're rendering an image via OpenGL, then you should choose this method, and only this method.

Comment: this is a 2 year old question. i'm no longer working on that iOS project. so i can't confirm if this answer is correct or not. sorry

Comment: Hopefully, it will be useful to someone else searching for an answer. Better luck on your new project!